# Instant communication with two pages without server using only jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have planned to create a blogger for quiz about php,javascript,jQuery and etc , here I am using localstorage for storing data, so I can communicate with two or more pages without server. But when I answer the first page the second page will automatically change the mark like facebook (If any friends give like without refresh get notified)

I think in asp.net (SignalR)
Like than have any possible to used in pure javascript.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you want, but the facebook thing is done using AJAX(I guess) and you have involvement of server there. The page is not refreshed but only specific part of it is updated. For AJAX see http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: in there one ajax is calling a server file like php or any other but here I can not able to use the server files, only html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to communicate between two pages within the same browser, you can utilize the [storage event](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#storage-event) to notify other browser windows on the same site of changes to localStorage.

If you want to communicate between different computers, you'll need some sort server to facilitate that communication.

Comment: When the storage value is change the function will called?

Comment: Where I need to put this "if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("storage", handle_storage, false);
} else {
  window.attachEvent("onstorage", handle_storage);
};"

Comment: This site provides a simple example of using storage events:
http://html5demos.com/storage-events